# WP7 + Waiting for an operation to complete before proceeding

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that is using Silverlight with C#. This application has a method that fires off multiple web service requests. At another point in my code, I have some code that looks like the following:

```
myProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
while (AreWebServiceCallsDone() == false)
{
  // Need "waiting" code here
}

// Proceed
```

How do I make my UI "wait" a small amount of time, without locking up the UI, and then check again to see if my web service calls are done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to not make the UI wait at all but to "go with the (asynchronous) flow", as it were.

Ultimately, the async stuff in C# 5 will solve this particular problem, but there's no timeline for it's release for the desktop CLR let alone Silverlight or WP7.

I'd personally recommend looking into `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive`, which is the WP7 version of the Reactive Extensions (Rx) and ships with the SDK. It's a pretty big subject that takes a fair amount of time to get your head around, but can really simplify how you deal with asynchronous scenarios.

Assuming each of your web services return different types of data, I would:

- Wrap each web service call in an IObservable<sup>1</sup>
- Use `Do` to "peek" at the message and perform your side effects (like assigning the value locally)
- Use `Select` to "normalize" the types so that they are all of the same type (required for the next step)
- Use `ForkJoin` to execute each of the requests in parallel and to handle when each has completed

<sup>1</sup> Creating an IObservable for your request really depends on how asynchronous pattern you are using. Assuming you're using `WebClient`, here's an extension method that creates an Observable from `DownloadStringAsync` as a sample (it may look complex but it's just handling errors and cancellation):

```
public static class ObservableWebClient
{
    public static IObservable<string> DownloadStringObservable(
        this WebClient webClient, Uri uri)
    {
        return Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

            var completedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<
                    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler, 
                    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs
                >(
                    h => new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(h),
                    h => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
                    h => webClient.DownloadStringCompleted h= h
                );

            disposable.Add(completedObservable
                .SelectMany(ev =>
                {
                    return (ev.EventArgs.Error != null)
                        ? Observable.Throw<string>(ev.EventArgs.Error)
                        : Observable.Return(ev.EventArgs.Result);
                })
                .Subscribe(observer));

            disposable.Add(Disposable.Create(
                () => webClient.CancelAsync()));

            return disposable;
        });
    }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

*Note that I've skipped the `Do` + "normalizing" steps because my data types are all the same (String). As such, I can subscribe to them all as an array (it's a subtlety of how `ForkJoin` works, if you were wondering)*

```
var webClientA = new WebClient();
var webClientB = new WebClient();
var webClientC = new WebClient();

Observable.ForkJoin(
        webClientA.DownloadStringObservable(uriA),
        webClientB.DownloadStringObservable(uriB),
        webClientC.DownloadStringObservable(uriC),
    )
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(dataArray =>
    {
        // All three have completed
        this.DataA = dataArray[0];
        this.DataB = dataArray[1];
        this.DataC = dataArray[2];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an async call back method and handle the progress bar's visibility on the call back event.

By using a **while**, you are making the UI wait for the thread to be executed.

I used this method in my blog post here: http://www.infopoint.com/News-Events/EntryId/29/Building-a-WP7-RSS-reader-Part-1-Basics.aspx